# how to dynamically root by both domain and subdomain in nginx config

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-10.04

I want to host several domain names, each with subdomains dynamically on my nginx server (ubuntu 14.04):

```
home/serve/
     domain1.com
        www
        subdomain1
        subdomain2
     domain2.com
        www
        subdomain1
        subdomain2
```

I want both www.domain1.com and domain1.com to root to /home/serve/domain1/www and subdomain1.domain1.com to root to /home/serve/domain1/subdomain1.

I have this working for the domain both with and without www. (see below) but I can't work out how I can extend this to enable the subdomain rooting as well.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;

    root       /home/serve/$domain/www/;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, if you set up a configuration like this, it's not easy to distinguish which part is domain and which is subdomain, i.e. if I go to `example.com`, is this the subdomain `example` of the domain `com`? Wait, if you handle it like that, it should work. You'd just have to create a directory `com` with a symlink called `example` which links to `example.com/www`.

Comment: @Carsten Yes, this is the issue I am coming up against with this approach, but so far this is the closest I have got to what I want. If this isn't a good way to go can you suggest an alternative.

Comment: Would my approach with the symlinks be feasible for you, though? Otherwise, do you have some information about the domains so that we could kill the ambiguosity somehow? Maybe requiring that the domain is two non-dot strings with a dot in between?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend your regular expression to include any subdomain, not just www. Also, it would be a good idea to set up the default folder in case the folder for the requested subdomain does not exist.

Something like this should work fine:

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w*?)?\.?(?<domain>\w+\.\w+)$;

if ($subdomain = "") {
    set $subdomain "www";
}

if (!-d "/home/serve/$domain/$subdomain") {
    set $subdomain "www";
}

root "/home/serve/$domain/$subdomain";
```

Note that even though using the "if" directive is usually inadvisable, in this particular case it is completely safe and acceptable, since these directives are defined in the server context.

Comment: This looks good, I will give it a try tomorrow and update then.  Thanks for commenting on your use of if statement in the case. I am so used to seeing the "IFISEVIL" warnings, that I immediately get nervous whenever I see it used.  I like the www fallback too.

Comment: This approach only works for single level subdomains and not sub.sub.domain.com, this is not a problem in my case but its good to note. The more important thing for me is that it does work with domains such as domain.co.uk